# Regex error in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I have simple code which doesn't work. It throws this error: what():  regex_error and I have no idea why. Thanks for any help. I tried to compile it with this flag: -std=c++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::regex r("[1-9]{4}");

    std::cout << "result: " << std::regex_match("1524", r) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using gcc? If so, the last release (4.8.1) ships with a broken/incomplete `regex` implementation. I believe a working implementation is available in the development branch, but that means having to compile gcc yourself.

Comment: hmm yes, I'm using gcc :) Thank you for answer.

Comment: Use Boost.Regex. That is a working almost compatible replacement. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html Many Linux distributions have boost. it also works with Windows (MSC++ and g++).